# Is it possible to read a string with newlines from the commandline

Tags: haskell, input

I have tried with 3 languages so far: Haskell, Python, Java.

I am a bit at a loss.

What I really want to do is the following:

```
*MyModule> myfunction arg1
                      arg1a
```

So my argument is actually a string containing a real newline.
Above the input for Haskell.

However, I have not found any examples for this, and when I try this with a real command line, I always get a crash because the interpreter or compiler assumes that at the linebreak there must surely be a new argument. 
Yes, I have tried to surround the string with "". No difference.

Is there an obvious way around this which I just have not found?

enable multiline gives the following error:

```
   lexical error in string/character literal at character '\n'
```

On request: The input I actually used was:

```
  3
  this is a test
  foobar
  all your base
```

Comment: What exactly have you entered to get that error? The examples in the answer are all valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GHCi session:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| 3 +
Prelude|   4 +
Prelude|   5
Prelude| :}
12
```

If you are trying to insert actual newlines in a string, I fear that this is indeed forbidden by Haskell, in favor of the following style:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| putStr "Hello\n\
Prelude|     \world!\n\
Prelude|     \ -- THE END\n"
Prelude| :}
Hello
world!
 -- THE END
```

Here we needed to use `\n` for explicit newlines. Also note that `\` has to be used *both* at the end-of-line and at the beginning of the next line. The spaces before the latter `\` will be ignored so to allow any indentation.

Also consider this style:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| putStrLn $ unlines
Prelude|   [ "Hello"
Prelude|   , "world!"
Prelude|   , " -- THE END"
Prelude|   ]
Prelude| :}
Hello
world!
 -- THE END
```

---

If all you need to do is reading the input, you can simply save it in a file (say `test.txt`) and read it as a string:

```
Prelude> test <- readFile "test.txt"
Prelude> putStr test
5
this is a test
foobar
all your base
class
pony along
```

Comment: Or we can also enable multiline mode `:set +m`

Comment: The solution with the brackets does not seem to work at all, the multiline code gives me an error, see edit above

Comment: to explain: I am trying to solve this old excercise for practicing purposes: http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard#s=p1  I have never participated in that, so I suppose I simply have to copy what they give as input into the command line.

Comment: I would try with java or python to but run into the same problem.

Comment: +chi, to simply save in a file and then read the file is of course possible and easy, but I do wonder if this is what is whished for in the exercise. Does not the exercise say it has to work from commandline somehow?

Comment: @user1862770 Such exercises typically assume input is provided as STDIN and output is expected to STDOUT. I'm also pretty sure that they do not require using GHCi at all -- programs will be compiled with `ghc` and then run (or run through interpreters, for other languages such as `python`).

Comment: @user1862770 Or even, in same contests, they will not ask for the program at all. They will provide a few input samples, and you are expected to upload the correct output -- it doesn't matter how you have generated that, as long it is exact. Try to check the FAQ/rules/whatever to see if there's more information somewhere for this particular contest.

Comment: Correct, you are requiered to upload the correct output, but the code also. I am not sure if they will really check the code.